# how to handle interactive notification when no action is performed and user taps on notification?

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

I am working on interactive notifications. I want user to perform atleast one action when notification get fired. but If in case user does not perform any action and directly tap on notification then app get launched.

I want to handle this like displaying alert that time when app launch.

does anyone have idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

Check if app is launching via taping notification. Write following in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

      if (launchOptions)
     {
           NSDictionary * appLaunchDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:launchOptions];

           NSDictionary* userInfo = [appLaunchDict objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
           if (userInfo){
           // Call your method here which will show alert or any thing you want.
           }
     }
}
```